# Free allocated by <canvas/> memory on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, memory-leaks

How can I free allocated memory by <canvas> in the following example:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <canvas id="canvas" width=3000 height=2000/>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillText("hao ar iu?", 20, 20);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to set *var canvas* to null (canvas = null), to delete canvas (delete canvas) or to dynamically create canvas and append it to the "document" root, after remove it that way:

```
<div onclick=reload()>CLICK TO RELOAD PAGE</div>
<script>
  function reload(){
    body.removeChild(canvas);
    location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

Nothing changes, the allocated memory gets larger and larger with every single page reload until my browser occupy too much of CPU RAM memory. Sometimes the browser crashes. Sometimes the garbage collector cleans up some of variables out scope. But it lets too much of memory occupied. I use Chrome version 25. Are there any means to free the <canvas> memory or to provoke early garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the JavaScript operator delete?

```
delete canvas;
```

Else you can try this that works for me:

```
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
```

You need to make sure to remove every reference to your canvas even the ones by the DOM or any other object to avoid the memory leaks.

PS: forgot to mention that your canvas size is very big. Keep your canvas size as small as possible to decrease memory use and increase fps.

PS2: closing your paths will help avoiding memory leaks

Comment: Yes I did try all of listed solutions by you, as you can read in my post. None of them seems to work reliable for me. What do you mean by "closing your paths"? I don't draw animation so the big size doesn't inflict performance in my case.

Comment: That is not what delete should be used for.